# Docker like solutions for OpenVZ containers

Tags: virtualization, openvz, docker

We have been providing OpenVZ containers(VEs) for developers working on some projects - this was done from a purely economical perspective. I have been asked to setup a Docker-like system within the OpenVZ containers for a continous integration solution. Unfortunately, OpenVZ containers cannot be used to run Docker.

Are there any alternative technologies/solutions for setting this up?

Answer (score 2):

The latest kernel update 2.6.32 042stab105.14 now supports Docker inside OpenVZ containers.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in theory to manage Parallels containers with Docker using libct library - https://github.com/xemul/libct.

Libct is a containers management library which provides convenient API for frontend programs to rule a container during its whole lifetime.